# IMacros Extract, How to extract title from html code using IMacros and RegEx?

Tags: regex, extract, eval, imacros

I want to extract the title from an HTML code, using Imacros and RegEx, the title is wrapped in some code that I want to filter out, I don't know how to use EVAL neither RegEx, I just found some RegEx that worked with my code, so it extracts the title from other codes,

but I am not sure how to use it with Imacros, appreciate it if anyone knows how to make it work, whether with RegEx or other ways.

Here is the html part:

```
<a data-test-id="search-guide" href="" title="Search for &quot;skin care routine&quot;"><div 
class="Jea Lfz XiG fZz gjz qDf zI7 iyn Hsu" style="white-space: nowrap; background-color: rgb(115, 
115, 115);"><div class="tBJ dyH iFc MF7 erh tg7 IZT mWe">Routine</div></div></a>
```

the part from the title I want is: skin care routine

the RexEx part that I use:

```
title="Search for &quot;([^"]*)&quot;
```

and here is my Imacros:

```
TAG POS=3 TYPE=a ATTR=data-test-id:search-guide EXTRACT=href
SET !VAR1 EVAL('s = '{{!EXTRACT}}'[title='Search for &quot;([^']*)&quot;]')
PROMPT {{!EXTRACT}}
```

I get an error on the EVAL Line:

```
 wrong format of SET command, line 15 (Error code: -910)
```

OK, I got it working, Here is the working code:

```
TAG POS=3 TYPE=A ATTR=data-test-id:search-guide EXTRACT=TITLE
SET !VAR1 EVAL("\"{{!EXTRACT}}\".substr(10,100);")
PROMPT {{!VAR1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Several "Mistakes" in your Script and Approach indeed...

'EXTRACT=HREF' won't get you anywhere, => simply use directly 'EXTRACT=TITLE' + 'EVAL()' (with 'replace()' if you don't mind keeping the Double Quotes, or 'split()' if you want to get rid of them)...
(Much easier without 'RegEx' anyway...)

(Spell "iMacros" correctly (x5) + Add a Question Mark to your Title (you are not sharing a 'HowTo'...) + Mention your FCI if you need me to "elaborate" in more Details...)

Comment: thanks for the tips, I finally got it working, I added the working code to my post.